# How long does the ball saver last in Pokemon Pinball: R&S?

Tags: pokemon-pinball-ruby-and-sapphire

In *Pokémon Pinball: Ruby & Sapphire*, there is a ball saver powerup. If the ball falls between the bumpers while the ball saver is active, Latios (*Ruby*) or Latias (*Sapphire*) will catch the ball and return it to Sproink so it can be relaunched.

How long does the ball saver stay active when a ball is launched for the first time? Does the ball saver disappear faster after a ball gets rescued?

[image: Latias ball saver on Sapphire Field]

Comment: As a bonus question, what actions activate the ball saver? I've seen evolution, egg hatching, and ball launching.